# Query items in nested XML

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing

I have the following XML:

```
<Vehicle>
  <Car>
    <Name>Audi</Name>
    <ModelList>
      <Model>A3</Model>
      <Model>A5</Model>
      <Model>A7</Model>
    </ModelList>
  </Car>
  <Car>
    <Name>Benz</Name>
    <ModelList>
      <Model>C Class</Model>
      <Model>E Class</Model>
      <Model>S Class</Model>
    </ModelList>
  </Car>
</Vehicle>
```

From this, how do I get the different models for the car name "Audi"?

I tried the following:

```
var h = from c in load.Descendants("Vehicle") 
        select new { model = c.Descendants("Car").Elements("ModelList").ToArray() };
```

But this gives me the all the models for "Audi" and "Benz". Where can I pass the name of the car here?

Comment: What have you tried, and which XML API are you using? (This is trivial in LINQ to XML.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to just a `Where` clause or `First` (or something similar) to perform the filtering.

If you know there will be exactly one car with the right name, you can use `Single`:

```
var models = load.Descendants("Car")
                 .Single(x => (string) x.Element("Name") == "Audi")
                 .Element("ModelList")
                 .Elements("Model")
                 .Select(x => (string) x);
```

Or if you don't know whether there could be multiple such elements (or none) and you're happy with a list of all models for all cars with a name of Audi:

```
var models = load.Descendants("Car")
                 .Where(x => (string) x.Element("Name") == "Audi")
                 .SelectMany(x => x.Element("ModelList").Elements("Model"))
                 .Select(x => (string) x);
```

The latter version in a query expression:

```
var models = from x in load.Descendants("Car")
             where (string) x.Element("Name") == "Audi"
             from model in x.Element("ModelList").Elements("Model")
             select (string) model;
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Linq to Sql:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("XMLFilePath");
var selectors3 = (from elements in doc.Element("Vehicle").Elements("Car")
                  where elements.Element("Name").Value == "Audi"
                  from items in elements.Element("ModelList").Elements("Model")
                  select items.Value).ToList();
```